# How can I allow these functions to work on every container that has this class

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on multiple owl slider that can filter slides using [OWL Carousel Filter](http://plugin.bearsthemes.com/jquery/OwlFilter/) by Bears Themes.

Here's my current code:

```
var owl = $('.sliderResource').owlCarousel({
        items   :3,
        loop    :true,
        margin  :40,
        nav     :true,
        dots    :true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            880:{
                items:2
            },
            1280:{
                items:3
            }
        }
    });

    /* animate filter */
    var owlAnimateFilter = function(even) {
        $(this)
        .addClass('__loading')
        .delay(70 * $(this).parent().index())
        .queue(function() {
            $(this).dequeue().removeClass('__loading')
        })
    }
    var data = [];
    $('.btn-filter-wrap').on('click', '.btn-filter', function(e) {
        var filter_data = $(this).data('filter');

        /* return if current */
        if($(this).hasClass('btn-active') && ($(this).data('filter')=='*')){
            return;
        }
        else if(!$(this).hasClass('btn-active') && ($(this).data('filter')=='*')){
            $(this).addClass('btn-active').siblings().removeClass('btn-active');
            data = '*';
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass('btn-active')){
            $(this).removeClass('btn-active');
            var remData = $(this).data('filter').toString();
            var idx = data.indexOf(remData);
            if (idx > -1) {
                data.splice(idx, 1);
            }
        }
        else{
            data = [];
            $(this).addClass('btn-active');
            $("[data-filter='*']").removeClass('btn-active');

            $.each($('.btn-filter'), function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('btn-active')){
                    data.push($(this).data('filter'));                  
                }
            });
        }

        /* Filter */
        if(data.length==0){
            data = '*';
        }
        owl.owlFilter(data, function(_owl) { 
            $(_owl).find('.item').each(owlAnimateFilter); 
        });

        return false;
    });
```

I want this to work on every `.btn-filter-wrap` on my page like using `each` function but jquery.owl-filter.js only works 'owl' variable resulting in triggering filter to all of the slider in my pages when you click a filter from a certain carousel

Comment: What is the problem here? when you are using  $('.btn-filter-wrap'), every matching element will be bound to the same event.

Comment: After 15 mins, i finally found the problem. jquery.owl-filter.js only use 'owl' as their variable in triggering filter but i dont know how to fix it